# WPF ClickOnce app have wrong start menu icon after update.

Tags: wpf, icons, clickonce

I have a WPF ClickOnce application where all the icons have been changed including the Application icon in Properties -> Application -> Icon and Manifest.

When installing the udated WPF app, where the updated version of the app is detected when running the original app, all icons are updated except the icon in the Start Menu (Windows 10 PC).

NOTE: Running the installation on a clean PC with no previous installation of the app will update the Start Menu icon to the new icon.

I have tried deleting the IconCache.db in %LocalAppData% and restarted the PC, but it is still the old Start Menu icon that is used.

Comment: Have you tried to open "Start menu" shortcut in any text editor and check what's a icon is for application deploy link there? I mean try to navigate on link and be sure there is correct icon on Install/Update prompt window.

Comment: Hi Sergey, you can open the file location for the shortcut and then open it in an editor like Notpad++, but it just contains unreadable stuff. Also when doing the installation on a "clean" PC the Start Menu icon is correct.

Comment: Have you tried to clean IE cache? May be it's cached if you have a correct icon for new PC.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too, but good point.

Comment: Crazy idea to find all .ico files on your C:\ and remove any olds :)